# unable to delete registry subkeytree using c#

Tags: c#, registry

> I want to delete folder **PackG3EGM** and all its sub directory using
>   c# but I am unable to delete it I don't know what's problem in my code 
>   below is my code

```
 string keyName = @"Software\PackG3EGM";
 using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
 {
                key.DeleteSubKeyTree("G3EGM", false);

 }
```

Comment: How is it failing? Are you getting an exception? Or is it failing quietly?

Comment: no error but still it doesnot delete folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open Software and specify PackG3EGM as the subkey to delete.

Also pass true to the throwOnMissingSubKey param, this will raise an exception if the specified subkey cannot be found

```
 string keyName = @"SOFTWARE";
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName, true))
            {
                key.DeleteSubKeyTree("PackG3EGM", true);

            }
```

Comment: it gives an error like "Cannot delete a subkey tree because the subkey does not exist.
"  but there is sub folder "G3EGM" under PackG3EGM  i want to delete main folder PackG3EGM

Comment: Which folder do you want to delete PackG3EGM  or G3EGM?

Comment: PackG3EGM folder i want to delete

Comment: Looks like PackG3EGM is not under Software then?

Comment: i can see PackG3EGM is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/PackG3EGM

Comment: still error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."